# Making members in subclasses readonly

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say I have the class A with member int `number` which has a getter and a setter.

Then I make a subclass of A and call it B. Now in the class B I wish to keep the member `number`, but in this class I want to impose the restriction that `number` is read-only. How can I do this?

Comment: What happens when you pass an instance of `B` to something expecting an `A` that tries to set `number`?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If you explain why you want to do that maybe we can give you a different approach.

Comment: Bad idea. Check out the Liskov Substitution Principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Answer (score 8):

The need for that is usually a hint that your design is not optimal (as it violates the Liskov substitution principle). Therefore, C# does not really support it. However, here are two ways to *kind of* implement it:

(1) Hide the property in the descendent and provide a new property that replaces the getter of the base class. But this does not really protect the property, since you can just cast to the base class:

```
class A
{
  public int Number { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
  public new int Number
  {
    get { return base.Number; }
  }
}

B b = new B();
// b.Number = 42; // This does not work.
A a = b;
a.Number = 42;
Console.WriteLine(b.Number); // == 42. Oops.
```

(2) Override the setter with an exception throw. But a wrong usage now causes a runtime error instead of a compiler error which is not nice. Consider adding a `bool CanSetNumber` property to the base (.NET does something similar with `Stream.CanSeek` and `Seek`).

```
class A
{
  public virtual int Number { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
  public override int Number
  {
    get { return base.Number; }
    set { throw new InvalidOperationException("B.Number is readonly!"); }
  }
}

B b = new B();
b.Number = 42; // BAM!
```

Comment: "Consider adding a bool CanSetNumber property to the base" - ... and do not forget to properly mention in the documentation of the base class that throwing an exception is one of the ways the property may legally behave! Otherwise, it can be said that the subclass does not fulfil the inherited interface.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Sebastian's answer. Another option to consider is to use a common interface instead of direct inheritance

```
public interface IHasNumber 
{
    int Number { get; }
}

public class A : IHasNumber 
{ 
    public int Number { get; set; } 
}
public class B : IHasNumber 
{ 
    public int Number { get; } 
}
```

If you want to share the values then you must encapsulate `A` in `B`.

```
public class B : IHasNumber 
{ 
    public B(A data) { this.Data = data; }
    private A Data { get; private set; }
    public int Number { get { Data.Number; } } 
 }
```

To be used as

```
{
    var A = new A();
    A.Number = 100;   // ok
    var B = new B(A);
    B.Number = 200;   // error
    Console.WriteLine(B.Number);  // prints 100
}
```