# How to show a property returns a copy (i.e. is immutable)

Tags: c#, immutability

Take the following snippet as an example:

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings;

    public JsonSerializerSettings Settings
    {
        get //Settings of JsonHelper should be immutable, that's why 'get' does not return the field _serializerSettings
        {
            return new JsonSerializerSettings() 
            {
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            };
        }
    }

    public JsonHelper()
    {
        _serializerSettings = Settings; 
    }
}
```

I don't want the `JsonSerializerSettings` to be changeable from the outside but I want to be able to offer these same settings in scenarios where I can't directly use `JsonHelper`.

Is there any way to signal to a user of this class that he can't do the following and expect the result s/he's expecting?

```
var instance = new JsonHelper();
instance.Settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

Or is the only way to create a method called `GetCopyOfSettings()`?

Comment: You could try this approach: [Make a subclass with properties made readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011576/1220550)

Comment: It would seem sensible to project to another class that contains the subset of properties that the consumer needs, but immutable. Have you ruled that out and why?

Comment: Make it a method, rename it to `CreateSettings`. Also, what is the purpose of `_serializerSettings`?